# Python matrix swapping columns using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, swap, floating-accuracy

This is my Y matrix I am trying to swap the columns (to make the columns [1,2,3,4,5] be in the place of [5,4,3,2,1])
But, this changes the numbers' accuracy

This is Y

```
> array([[ 0.0e+00,  1.0e-15,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00],
>        [ 1.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00],
>        [-1.0e-02,  1.2e-02,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00],
>        [ 1.0e-02, -1.0e-02,  1.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00]])
```

This the code

```
y1, y2= np.shape(Y)
 y2= y2-2
 for row in range (y1):
     for column in range (y2):
         Z[row, column]=Y[row, y2-column+1]
```

This is Z

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

How can I make it have the same accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't loop here, simply use [**`np.flip`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html)

```
x = np.array([[ 0.0e+00,  1.0e-15,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00],
    [ 1.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00],
    [-1.0e-02,  1.2e-02,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00],
    [ 1.0e-02, -1.0e-02,  1.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00]])

np.flip(x, axis=1)

array([[ 0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  1.0e-15,  0.0e+00],
       [ 0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  1.0e+00],
       [ 0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  1.2e-02, -1.0e-02],
       [ 0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  1.0e+00, -1.0e-02,  1.0e-02]])
```

If you have a different order in mind, for example: `4, 3, 5, 2, 1`, you can make use of advanced indexing:

```
x[:, [3, 2, 4, 1, 0]]

array([[ 0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  1.0e-15,  0.0e+00],
   [ 0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  1.0e+00],
   [ 0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  0.0e+00,  1.2e-02, -1.0e-02],
   [ 0.0e+00,  1.0e+00,  0.0e+00, -1.0e-02,  1.0e-02]])
```

Comment: Looping and using y2= y2-2 made some columns not in the new matrix, So, these are different numbers not different accuracy.